# How do you make the Blade of Grass?

Tags: terraria

What do you need to make the Blade of Grass weapon?

Answer (score 2):

The [Blade of Grass](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blade_of_Grass) is crafted at an anvil using 12 Jungle Spores and 12 (15 on mobile) Stingers.

Answer (score -1):

https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Blade_of_Grass 
If you are looking for crafting tips I highly suggest this wiki. It has helped me throughout my playthrough

Comment: Please provide some details from the link, to avoid loss of information due to link rot.